# Inserting a list into a string

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I think I wasn't clear in my last question, in case this looks familiar to someone.

```
#!/bin/bash
STATE= xml sel -t -v "/PATH/TO/VALUE/@state" ListOfStates.xml
```

This produces a list that looks kind of like this

```
TEXAS
COLORADO
NEW YORK
FLORIDA 
CALIFORNIA
```

I want to take each line and insert it into echo command, or a .txt, like so:

```
FileName="STATE_${STATE}"
echo $FileName
```

The output looks like this:

```
TEXAS
COLORADO
NEW YORK
FLORIDA
CALIFORNIA
STATE_
```

Instead my output should look like this

```
 STATE_TEXAS
 STATE_COLORADO
 STATE_NEW YORK
 STATE_FLORIDA
 STATE_CALIFORNIA
```

Comment: `STATE= xml sel -t -v "/PATH/TO/VALUE/@state" ListOfStates.xml` , 100% does not work.

Comment: Are you sure? I just ran `xml sel -t -v "/PATH/TO/VALUE/@state" ListOfStates.xml` and it outputted the list above.

Comment: The assignment is incorrect, not the xml command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
xml sel -t -v "/PATH/TO/VALUE/@state" ListOfStates.xml | sed 's/^/STATE_/'
```

and if you want to store it into an array:

```
IFS=$'\n' arr=($(xml sel -t -v "/PATH/TO/VALUE/@state" ListOfStates.xml | sed 's/^/STATE_/'))
```

Comment: No need for the `g` modifier since `^` matches start of string

Comment: And your second example create an array with the following: `xml`, `sel`, `-t`, `-v`, ... if it doesn't fail because of the pipe `|`

Comment: Also the array one will mess up for `new york`

Comment: @ritesht93 So I would love to get the array working, heres what I did  `IFS=$'\n' STATE=($(xml sel -t -v "/PATH/TO/VALUE/@state" ListOfStates.xml | sed 's/^/STATE_/'))` and then I echo that array right? `echo $STATE` ... it lines up perfectly, except instead of outputting all states it only outputs the first line: `STATE_TEXAS`

Comment: @buzzin use this: `echo ${STATE[@]}`

Comment: @ritesht93 yessir that was it thank you, although I lost the formatting, everything was on one line. I ended up using `printf "%s\n" ${STATE[*]}` which put each each state on a seperate line

Answer (score 0):

```
xml sel -t -m '//path/to/element' -v 'concat("STATE_", @state)' -nl ListOfStates.xml
```

Comment: This is identical to an answer posted 5 minutes before it minus the `g` flag in the sub...

Comment: True, but I had not seen that answer yet.